# IE 8 CSS, Submenus not displaying when hovering over the navigation items at http://kabenwireless.net/

Tags: css, internet-explorer, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, stylesheet

I'm working on this website for a company and I'm having issues with the CSS in IE8 that allows the sub menus to appear when you hover over the navigation tabs.

http://kabenwireless.net/

When you hover over some of the menu items in the navigation, there is supposed to be a sub menu that appears. This does not work in IE8, but it does work in all other browsers other than IE.

Any help is appreciated in getting these styles to work in IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem is that on `#access`, you're using `filter` for opacity:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=95)";
filter: alpha(opacity=95);
```

Using those `filter`s causes an `overflow: hidden`-esque effect. It's like `#access` has `overflow: hidden`. You can see why that would stop your submenus showing up.

You need to either not use opacity for IE, or you need to refactor how you're applying the opacity bearing in mind the `overflow: hidden` effect.

Applying the opacity to *only* the dropdowns would probably work.

Maybe CSS3 PIE (which you're already using) can help you. Look up how to do `rgba` with it, it's something like `-pie-background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`.

---

You can quickly verify what I'm saying as true by:

- Opening your site in IE8.
- Pressing F12 to open the Developer Tools.
- Inspecting `<div id="access">`.
- Unticking the `filter` rule in the right-hand panel.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But the issue now is that there is still a bouncy effect going on when I hover my mouse. The div adjusts itself weirdly and takes a second to become normal. How do I fix that?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. That's not something I know off the top of my head - it's going to need thorough investigation. My instinct is that it's to do with CSS3 PIE. Poke around the documentation, maybe `-pie-poll: true` will help. I will look at this again in a few hours if you haven't managed to sort it out by then. Good luck :)

Comment: It seems to be the IE7-JS script. When I remove it, all of my CSS3 features go away, but so does the problem. For some reason, both pie and ie7-js are needed together. I can't understand it...

Comment: I disabled the IE7JS script for now. Better to function well then look well.